# Vite keeps refreshing the entire page

Tags: vite

I migrated from CRA to Vite and it keeps refreshing the entire page.

I saw [this issue #7131](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7131) on GitHub and that's not my problem.

Here's my `vite.config.js`:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
const path = require(`path`)
const aliases = {
  '@Form': 'src/Components/Form/Exports',
  '@List': 'src/Components/List/Exports',
  '@Browse': 'src/Components/Browse/Browse',
  '@Tree': 'src/Components/Tree/Exports',
  '@Tab': 'src/Components/Tab/Exports',
  '@Dashboard': 'src/Components/Dashboard/Dashboard',
  '@Panel': 'src/Panel/Panel',
}

const resolvedAliases = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(aliases).map(([key, value]) => [key, path.resolve(__dirname, value)]),
)

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, '.')

  console.log(env)

  const htmlPlugin = () => {
    return {
      name: "html-transform",
      transformIndexHtml(html) {
        return html.replace(/%(.*?)%/g, function (match, p1) {
          return env[p1]
        })
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    resolve: {
      alias: resolvedAliases
    },
    plugins: [react(), htmlPlugin()],
    server: {
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      hmr: {
        clientPort: 443
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Since my project contains hundreds of components, and it use OAuth and third party authenticators, each reload takes a considerable amount of time (maybe 5 seconds).

This hugely slows down the development.

What should I do to fix this?
What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: Can you share a link to a minimum reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @tony19, I'll try to create a repo. But I can also give you remote access, since it's a real-world application and I literally have no idea where the problem can come from.

Comment: The minimal repro would be best, but I can take a peek at your git repo when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

Please do ensure you check wether you are exporting something or variable that is not a react component in my case i discovered i did this and anytime i save it kept refreshing the entire ui

```
export const services=[]
```

Rather i created a seperate file and declared it and used

```
const services=[];
export default services
```